# Classic ASP/VBScript Client Side CreateObject( "ADODB.Recordset" ) returning empty

Tags: vbscript, adodb, recordset, is-empty, createobject

Looking for assistance troubleshooting/diagnosing an issue that is showing up with a Classic ASP/VBScript web application I am currently supporting. Over the past couple of weeks I've had users reporting issues in the app, troubleshooting with them I've been able to narrow down the issue to creation of a "ADODB.Recordset" in client side VB Script.

To test/confirm this I added the below to a dev environment and had the users experiencing issues connect.

```
Dim testRs              

set testRs = CreateObject( "ADODB.Recordset") 

msgbox TypeName(testRs)
```

What I am seeing is the users having issues are getting "Empty" back. Users not experiencing the issue get a type back of RecordSet. For the users experiencing issues this leads to a *424 object required error* when attempting to do anything with the recordset object, in this case just an open on a URL.

To be clear this is currently a workstation specific issue, the users reporting problems are not experiencing problems on another workstation. I'm currently working with them to identify what may have changed but we haven't been able to pinpoint anything yet. We are all on Windows 7 Enterprise, using IE11.

This is an older application, nothing has changed in quite some time. I've confirmed all users are accessing the site in compatibility mode (intranet site).

If anyone can provide guidance/insight on how I can further troubleshoot/pinpoint the issue I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: On the machines experiencing the problem is MDAC installed?

Comment: Yes, confirmed the version is the same as my workstation where the problem is not occurring(checked registry). I'm going to request MDAC be reinstalled as a test but I would expect some type of error back if it were missing instead of just 'Empty'.

Comment: Possibly the COM entries in the `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT` for the `ADODB.Recordset` prog-id have become corrupt? Must admit, never had this issue myself.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this bug too for a really old classic asp app and it turned out to be the app pool setting in IIS for Windows 10.

open IIS.

select application pools in left frame

right click your app pool

in the middle frame under 'general' section for the 'enable    32 bit applications' set to true